# Como eliminar linhas de um datagridview

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

Eu estou a desenvolver um programa em C# e gostaria de saber como posso bloquear/eliminar uma linha de sql no `datagridview`.
A linha que eu queria eliminar/bloquear é essa ultima que esta selecionada na print, queria saber se é possível bloquear ou eliminar pois da para escrever nessa linha. 
Não posso também usar o `enable=false;` porque eu quando clico no `datagridview` ele escreve na `textbox` o que está selecionado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tenta colocar  a propriedade AllowUserToAddRows = false;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para ocultar a linha de adição de novas linhas, vai nas propriedades do datagridview e Set

> AllowUserToAddRows=false;

[image]